# Should I delete and repost my question to regenerate interest?

Tags: discussion

I posted this question a couple of days ago: [Blending values on the number line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117176/blending-values-on-the-number-line).

It got two fairly speedy responses, but my question really wasn't worded properly. I've since edited it, but it isn't generating any additional responses/interest. I'm fairly sure that if it was a brand new question again it would have more visibility. Is it acceptable for me to delete and repost it?

Comment: I greatly appreciate your asking ahead of time before doing this; many people don't.

Comment: There is also the option of adding a bounty. I don't know that the points actually motivate people (I hope not, at least), but it does make the question more visible.

Comment: However, do this sparingly.  Do not hog the space on the front page!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't delete and repost; for one thing, you will deprive the people who already gave you answers of any reputation they gained from those answers, and you will make their work moot.

Instead, **edit** the question. That will automatically bump it to the top of the activity list. You can also take the opportunity to re-word it properly.

Be sure to specify that you have edited (and perhaps subtly changed) the question so that later readers don't penalize the people who already replied, thinking that their answers are incorrect or miss the point.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @PUK: Just to add, if the edit changes the question significantly, keep the old one and add a new one, rather than editing the old one, potentially making the answers irrelevant.