# How to draw attention to an old question?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3489525/for-what-measures-of-%E2%88%A0a-are-there-infinitely-many-intersections) a few months ago but after a few days it began getting less and less traffic, so I put a bounty on it. The question was answered, but was done so using a computer program to approximate the solution. I was dissatisfied with this answer, largely because I was never interested with the number(s) themselves but how they were obtained, and I wanted a more mathematical solution. The bounty expired and for the last few months the question has since been inactive. I do not have social media so posting the link is not an option. Without another bounty is there any way to get more attention? Are you allowed to re-post the question?

Comment: See also: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478)

Comment: You have also mentioned that you're not really satisfied with result of your bounty. One should not overestimate the impact of offering a bounty. See this question for some stats: [How effective are bounties?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20155) (Other [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20155) might be of interst, too.)

Comment: You have also asked whether to repost the question. That is not a good idea, you can find some related discussions here on meta. For example: [Is double posting allowed if a question is not answered after some time?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26282) or [Should I delete and repost my question to regenerate interest?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3795)